# TideSDK and native code?

Tags: tidesdk

I've just discovered TideSDK and it seems to be a really great tool, but I have one requirement : I need to use some native code (for managing USB devices for example) and so I need communication between this native code and the web app, is such a thing possible  with TideSDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, working with native code in TideSDK is possible. Our SDK is modular and we have been reorganizing the code structurally to make it easier to do the sort of thing you want. At a modular level, you will be contending with support for multiple platforms typically.

A module should extend to all platforms that you are supporting. We expect to have documentation to help developers (familiar with native code) to better understand the SDK. This should include some module boilerplate to help you get started. At this point, we have yet to prepare this more detailed documentation. We have much to do and sometimes progress seems slow despite all the great efforts going into TideSDK.

TideSDK is a large and complex SDK but don't let this frighten you off. It is extensible and we will be shining light on this soon with module development guides. It would be cool to talk more on IRC about this with you so feel free to drop by at any time. Perhaps the functionality you are speaking of is of general use ie. to extend the APIs for everyone.

There are possibilities to work together with the core developers of TideSDK on modules and to contribute to this great open source project. Other possibilities also include sponsoring module development if this something that you need more immediately for a project. Hope this helps.